# Update Maven dependencies automatically

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

I have a significant number of Maven projects in Eclipse, with quite a lot of dependencies.

Some of the dependencies are frequently being updated in repositories as new versions are released. Currently I have to look out for these manually, and manually edit the respective `pom.xml`s to use the new version.

Is there an automatic way to do the following in Eclipse:

- Check whether newer versions of each dependency are available?
- If so, automatically suggest changes to the `pom.xml` (like a "quick fix" feature)?

Comment: see https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-latest-version

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for maven [versions plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/):

> **versions:display-dependency-updates**   Displays all dependencies that
>   have newer versions available.

This will show a list of all updated dependencies. There is a similar command to show a list of all the updated plugins.

There doesn't seem to be a command to update the dependencies to their latest versions automatically. From the docs it looks like you can use the `versions:display-property-updates` to update the dependency versions if they are specified as properties in the pom file.

Comment: +1, @Abhinav Sarkar. Thank you for the reference. I did not know about it. I can also recommend to just remove the `<version>` tag from `<dependency>`. In this case maven tries to retrieve the newest version.

Comment: Removing the `<version>` tag is a very bad idea. You completely lose control over all the dependencies of your projects and automatic updates can break your project any time. I strongly recommend against it. You should always update the dependency versions after thoroughly checking that the updates don't break your code.

Answer (score 0):

When using Github you could use the Dependabot GitHub plugin, it generates a pull-request for each dependency needing an update.