# How to make sure that everyone who commits a new branch has the changes reflected in the pom.xml?

Tags: git, maven, githooks

Is there a way I can automatically update a pom.xml file on a git commit using a git commit hook?

What I want to do, is I want to replace all instances of the old version, with the new version based on the branch name.

For example.

If I check out from master I might find in my pom.xml

```
<dependancy>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>my_component</artifactId>
  <version>master-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependancy>
```

or

```
<groupId>com.mycompany.project</groupId>

    <artifactId>mainProject</artifactId>
    <version>master-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mainProject</name>
```

What I would like to do, is to make sure that everyone who commits a new branch, has that new branch reflected in the pom.xml.   So if I create a new branch based on master named "myNewBranch", I would like the pom.xml to be automatically updated to the following:

```
<dependancy>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>my_component</artifactId>
  <version>myNewBranch-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependancy>
```

or

```
<groupId>com.mycompany.project</groupId>

    <artifactId>mainProject</artifactId>
    <version>myNewBranch-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mainProject</name>
```

Comment: Even if I understand your need, this could lead to painful merges between two branches, since every pom.xml would be modified at the same lines.

Comment: @noahlz That looks like it would do the trick. How do I pull the git branch name as a variable?

Comment: @GuillaumeDarmont well right now we are doing it manually, I'd like to automate it.

Comment: Related: [Update Maven dependencies automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12551031/55075).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking to do something that is not provided "out of the box" by core Maven or the [Maven SCM plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/plugin-info.html).

You'll have to write a shell script that runs on post-commit that programmatically obtains (or creates) the branch name as per [How to programmatically determine the current checked out Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593051/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-current-checked-out-git-branch) and then calls `mvn versions:set`

You could also do something like make a custom Maven plugin or [maven-ant-run](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) execution to do this, but I think the script approach will be the path of least resistance for you.